# OData / WCF Data Services Client Library, DataServiceContext.UpdateObject changes the URL

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

I am consuming Java Odata service using dotnet WCF Data Service Client Library.

There is strange problem which I am facing.
After adding object into "DataServiceContext.UpdateObject" my URL for update object changes and when I call "DataServiceContext.SaveChanges()" I am getting error.

After adding Update object

```
context url: http://v-bon:8080/RebalanceEngine/RestletServlet/Rebalance
EditLink url: http://v-bon:8080/Rebalance/RebalanceResponses(1)




context.UpdateObject(oObject);

DataServiceResponse response = context.SaveChanges();
```

Error I am getting. "Access to the specified resource has been forbidden."

[image: UpdateObject URL Screenshot]

Comment: How did the object you're updating get added to the context? Could you include that code as well?

Comment: I am getting object from service before I am updating it. I have found in fiddler that the response contains hardcoded URL which is wrong. I have raised this to the other team. I Think that is the problem.